# JSF resource using EL - faces 2.2.9 stop working

Tags: jsf, jsf-2.2, myfaces, apache-tomee, tomee-7

The code below used to be working when I was using faces 2.1.7.  But, it fails to work after I changed my TomEE 7 to use faces 2.2.9.

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="#{resource['default:css/main.css']}&amp;v=#{config['css.version']}" type="text/css" />
```

In 2.2.9 it generates the following code:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="&amp;v=css9.999" type="text/css" />
```

Any idea why it is not generating the `#{resource['default:css/main.css']}` EL expression?

Comment: Which JSF implementation are you using?

Comment: I'd guess MyFaces. It's TomEE and current latest MyFaces version is 2.2.9 (TomEE originally bundles MyFaces and current latest Mojarra version is 2.2.12).

Comment: I download TOMEE plus from http://www.apache.org/dyn/closer.cgi/tomee/tomee-1.7.3/apache-tomee-1.7.3-plus.zip.  It comes with myfaces 2.1.17, which is what I had been using for the past 8 months.  Yesterday, I replaced the myfaces-api-2.1.17.jar and myfaces-impl-2.1.17.jar in the TOMEE lib folder with myfaces-api-2.2.9.jar and myfaces-impl-2.2.9.jar, and that is when the problem starts to happen.

Comment: anyone has instructions on how to change TomEE Plus 1.7.2's myfaces 2.1.17 to myfaces2.2.9?  I don't think it is any simple as replacing the myface-api and myfaces-impl files, as I initially thought.

Comment: It turns out that to change TomEE+ 1.7.2 to use myfaces2.2.9 is as simple as replacing the myface-api and myfaces-impl files (+missing dependent jars).  My problem turns out to be caused by javax.faces.WEBAPP_RESOURCES_DIRECTORY setting.  It was set as /resources.  After I changed it to resources (without the /), it started to work.  Strange that myfaces 2.1.17 is ok with /resources.